# Correct way to write "save them 20 days of labor per month"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am stuck in trying to figure out how to say that automation saved a company X days of labor every month.

Is writing *save them 20 days of labor per month* the correct way? Is there a better way to express the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some unit of labor like **"man hours"**.

> The automation company saved them 20 *man hours* of work every week.

Comment: Of course also **man days.**

Comment: Sure, man weeks, man months, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The word *man hour* is the most appropriate term, but I don't see any problem in using *workday (work day)* which means

> the period of time in a day during which work is performed

If workday at X company is 8 hours and you say,

> It can save X company 20 work days per month

it would have the same meaning as

> It can save X company 160 man hours per month.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for the gender-neutral term *work hours* or *working hours*. Of course, one could use *work/working days, years,* etc.

In my experience, I see *work hours*, *work days*, and *work years* more often than *working hours*, *working days*, and *working years*, so for the purpose of this answer, I'll use those, but both *work* and *working* are perfectly acceptable gender-neutral options.

Your example:

> Automation saved the company X *work hours* per month.
>
> Automation saved the company X *work days* per month.